# Страница пользователя php, mysql

Tags: php

Суть в том, чтобы только что зарегистрированный пользователь попал на чистую, незаполненную страницу, адрес которой [www.example.ru/00*](http://www.example.ru/00*), а вместо звездочки его id, который в базу попадает одновременно с введенными при регистрации данными. Как мне осуществить это направление через header? Тут работают сессии, т.е нужно их учитывать.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: по кнопке отправляется форма, на сайт index.php, там просходт запись в базу, тут же идёт запрос из sql уникальный мы знаем только при регистрации почту или телефон, и при запросе выводим id и подставляем header

Comment: извлекаешь при регистрации идентификатор юзера с помощью `last_insert_id` и делаешь `header("location: /$id")`, что еще тут может вопросы вызывать?

Comment: Логику я понимаю, можете написать конкретный код для хедера? И что мне нужно  в начале страницы пользователя запросить из базы/проверить?

Comment: тебе надо сначала определиться, чего ты хочешь. А то ты рот слишком широко разеваешь - и хидер у тебя и сессии и страницу показать. Реши сначала одну проблему, потом занимайся другой

Comment: $loo="main.php";
header("Location: http://main/suite/".$loo);

Comment: Никаких ноликов в адресе страницы быть не должно.   
адрес должен быть www.example.com/profile.php у всех пользователей.

После регистрации получить айди, записать в сессию и перенаправить на страницу профиля.   
На ней - сюрприз!  - достать из сессии ид, и по нему отобразить ту инфу, которую пользователь ввел при регистрации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не слушайте г-на @`Ипатьев` несмотря на большое кол-во репутации на данном сайте он пишет о том в чем явно не разбирается. Вы вольны делать такие линки какие пожелаете. Желаете сделать

> site.com/user/`<id>` или site.com/`<id>`

Нет проблем! Вам нужно, чтобы описанный Вами `URL` обрабатывал какой-то конкретный Ваш `php`-файл. Это называется `routing` (роутинг). Во всех популярных `PHP`-фреймворках он есть. Если же Вам нужно это сделать на `pure` (чистом) или как говорят `native`-php - все что нужно описать это роутинг в правилах Вашего веб-сервера. Если у Вас `apache` то это `.htacces`. Для начала подключите в конфиге `Apache` модуль `mod_rewrite` инструкцией

> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

после чего в `.htaccess` пропишите следущие правила

> RewriteEngine on
>
> `#` не позволять httpd отдавать файлы, начинающиеся с точки (.htaccess, .svn, .git и прочие)
> RedirectMatch 403 /..*$
>
> `#` если директория или файл существуют использовать их напрямую
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> `#` иначе все запросы вида `site.com/00<число>` отправлять
> на файл user.php с параметром id равным указанному числу
>
> RewriteRule ^00(\d+)$ /user.php/?id=$1 [L]

Например при обращении пользователя к `URL` Вашего сайта `site.com/00354`, Вы в файле `user.php` в глобальном массиве `$_GET` получите переменную `id` со значением `354`.

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, в чем сложность. Просто данные в функцию **header('Location: [http://www.example.ru/00{$id}'](http://www.example.ru/00%7B$id%7D%27));**. ID пользователя у тебя есть. Скорее всего в сессии уже хранится. Если трудность в том, что бы получить ID только что зарегистрированного пользователя, то через MySQL получаешь последний Insert ID через mysqli_insert_id(), если не ошибаюсь (расширение mysqli)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115803/discussion-on-answer-by-kernelsource---php-mysql).